# Pushing random array elements into another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array consisting of N>10 URLs. I want to randomly pick 10 of them and store them in another array. How can I achieve this? Is `array_rand()` the way to go? If yes, then how do I ensure that there are no duplicities in the output array? Do I have to check the second array everytime a new element is added for existence?

```
// $firstArray is defined earlier
$secondArray = array();
array_push(array_rand($firstArray, 10));
```

This doesn't work unfortunately. I was thinking about using a for cycle for the `array_push()` but I was just curious if `array_rand()` can do that for me.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: You could make a copy of your original array so the first stays intact. Then as you select a random element use unset to remove the element from the copied array. That way you wouldn't get any duplicates.

Comment: Have you RTFM what [`array_rand`](http://php.net/array_rand) does and how it's supposed to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

array_rand returns keys so

```
$randKeys = array_rand($firstArray, 10);
foreach($randKeys as $key)
$secondArray[] = $firstArray[$key]
```

Comment: even i use array_rand for random values but here i am worried about "No duplicate" protocol. Are you sure that there will be no duplicates in resulting array by using this approach?

Comment: `$second = array_intersect_key($first, array_flip(array_rand($first, 10)));` :)

Comment: @Bhavik As long as the first array doesn't have duplicates, yes.

Comment: @deceze: Would you like to show me some good reason to be sure of that. I have read the official documentation about array_rand but didnt found any note anywhere mentioning your supposal

Comment: @Bhavik Well, in fact, I can't prove it. I guess it goes pretty much without saying that the returned keys are unique. But you're right, it's nowhere said explicitly. I thereby dare you to prove that `array_rand` *may* return duplicate keys! ;)

Comment: @deceze: I can't prove my stand either. But, i have learned a better way to eradicate that small tiny little chance. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928167/pushing-random-array-elements-into-another-array-in-php/19928289#comment-29654170). Would like to listen on this from you.

Comment: @deceze: here comes the another approach. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928167/pushing-random-array-elements-into-another-array-in-php/19928289#answer-19928444)

Comment: @Bhavik Well, `array_rand` is either made to return elements regardless of whether they're duplicates or it's designed to return unique keys. Since the second parameter cannot be larger than the number of items in the array and [this](http://3v4l.org/lQG8N) returns the same result every time, I'd say it's made to return unique keys. Therefore there's no "small chance" you'll get duplicates and cargo cult programming is unnecessary.

Comment: using `array_rand(array_flip($array), 10)` as in my answer below would remove the duplicates problem, when the duplicated values switches to keys they will replace each other, removing the other duplicated keys, it's a bit hacky but works XD

Comment: @deceze: Well, i dont want to get into altercation with you anymore. You enjoy your way and i will adopt my way. It was nice to have responses from you.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without `array_rand()`. Use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle) to shuffle the array elements and then use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) to get the first 10 items:

```
$secondArray = array();
shuffle($firstArray);
$secondArray = array_slice($firstArray, 0, 10);
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/66501)

Answer (score 2):

As people said there is a second argument in `array_rand()` to pick how many random elements you want, always remember to read the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

```
//Lets pick 10 mammals
$mammals = array('dog', 'cat', 'pig', 'horse', 'bat', 'mouse', 'platypus', 'bear', 'donkey', 'deer', 'hog', 'duck');
$ten = array_rand(array_flip($mammals), 10);

//If what yo u really wanted is to append them to another array, let's say "animals":
$animals = array('fish', 'crab', 'whale', 'eagle');
$animals = array_merge($animals, array_rand(array_flip($mammals), 10));
```

**Explanation**
`array_rand()` will return you the keys, so we can use `array_flip()` here to reverse the keys => values positions before picking them, no need to loop through them again.

And using `array_merge()` we merge them together, with no need to loop through the ten random elements to add them one by one, unless ... you want a specific order or other logic.

Answer (score 1):

Not very optimized solution, but for small amounts of data it may suit:

```
$firstArray = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$secondArray = array();

$tmp = array_unique($firstArray);
shuffle($tmp);
$secondArray += array_slice($tmp,0, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use array_push like in the example code, the last index in your second array will contain the returned 10 indexes

Eg.

```
$stack = array('a', 'b', 'c');
array_push($stack, array('d', 'e', 'f'));
print_r($stack);

Array (
  [0] => a
  [1] => b
  [2] => c
  [3] => Array (
     [0] => d
     [1] => e
     [2] => f
  )
)
```

I would use a while in this case and pick only one value at a time. Something like:

```
$stack = array();
while(count($stack)<10){
    $item = array_rand($collection_of_urls);
    if(!in_array($item)
        array_push($stack, $item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this simple

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 10);
print_r($rand_keys);
```